# Dropdown with data toggle keeps two options selected

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a dropdown menu with contains a data toggle for tabs. I have the problem that once I selected an item, the item stays selected and stays blue.

Any ways to fix this?

[image]

Code:

```
    <ul class='nav nav-tabs'>
    <li class='nav-item'>
      <a class='nav-link active' data-toggle='tab' href='#overall'>Overall</a>
    </li>
    <li class='nav-item'>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Classes
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
              <button class="dropdown-item" data-toggle='tab' href="#zombie" type="button" aria-selected="true" >Zombie</button>
              <button class="dropdown-item" data-toggle='tab' href="#spider" type="button"aria-selected="false">Spider</button>
              <button class="dropdown-item" data-toggle='tab' href="#enderman" type="button"aria-selected="false">Enderman</button>
            </div>
          </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
    <div class='tab-content'>
    <div class='tab-pane container active' id='overall'>
    blabla
    </div>
    <div class='tab-pane container' id='zombie'>
        zombie
    </div>
    <div class='tab-pane container' id='spider'>
        Spider
    </div>
    <div class='tab-pane container' id='enderman'>
        Enderman
    </div></div>
```

Comment: Is that all of the relevant code?

Comment: @Zim yes, everything.

Comment: I don't see the button that triggers the dropdown. Anyway tabs work of `nav-tabs` and `nav-link` so I don't think it will work with `dropdown-item`.

Comment: the div of the dropdown is part of  ` <ul class='nav nav-tabs'>
    <li class='nav-item'>
      <a class='nav-link active' data-toggle='tab' href='#overall'>Overall</a>
    </li>
    <li class='nav-item'>
        <div class="dropdown"> .....`

Comment: @Zim i updated the code above. sorry

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a **id="dropdown-menu"** next to **class="dropdown-menu"**. This would be more convenient. reference line -20.
2. Make a Javascript that will add **.active** class in your clicked area/HTML. For example if you click on

`<button class="dropdown-item" data-toggle='tab' href="#zombie" type="button" aria-selected="true" >Zombie</button>`

that will add **.active** class in there

`<button class="dropdown-item class" data-toggle='tab' href="#zombie" type="button" aria-selected="true" >Zombie</button>`

And it will remove **.active** class from the previous position. This **.active** class is a Bootstrap class. It will render CSS style from Bootstrap.

Code below-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css"/>
<title>HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <ul class='nav nav-tabs'>
    <li class='nav-item'>
      <a class='nav-link active' data-toggle='tab' href='#overall'>Overall</a>
    </li>
    <li class='nav-item'>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Classes
            </button>
            <div id="dropdown-menu" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
              <button class="dropdown-item" data-toggle='tab' href="#zombie" type="button" aria-selected="true" >Zombie</button>
              <button class="dropdown-item" data-toggle='tab' href="#spider" type="button"aria-selected="false">Spider</button>
              <button class="dropdown-item" data-toggle='tab' href="#enderman" type="button"aria-selected="false">Enderman</button>
            </div>
          </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
    <div class='tab-content'>
    <div class='tab-pane container active' id='overall'>
    blabla
    </div>
    <div class='tab-pane container' id='zombie'>
        zombie
    </div>
    <div class='tab-pane container' id='spider'>
        Spider
    </div>
    <div class='tab-pane container' id='enderman'>
        Enderman
    </div></div>
<script>
  var header = document.getElementById("dropdown-menu");
  var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-item");
  for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
    document.getElementById("overall").innerHTML = this.innerText;
    });
  }
</script>
  
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```